# CSS Menu (hide UL)

Tags: css

I'm new to CSS and I'm trying to make a menu where the sub-list is only visible (and takes up space) on hover-over.

I've found the `visibility:collapse;` property, but that only masks the sub-list and leaves a big gaping gap in my vertical menu.

Here's what I've got so far, but I'm not sure how to implement the expandable sub-menu on hover over:

CSS:

```
nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; 
}

nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

nav ul li ul {
    visibility: collapse;
}
```

HTML:

```
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="gear.html">Gear</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="p1.html">P1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="p2.html">P2>/a></li>
                    <li><a href="p3.html">P3/a></li>
                    <li><a href="p4.html">P4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="p5.html">P5</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="news.html">News</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li> 
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

Any help you can offer is much appreciated

Comment: You have to use javascript for getting an expandable submenu on hover.

Comment: [If used on elements other than rows, row groups, columns, or column groups, 'collapse' has the same meaning as 'hidden'](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visufx.html#visibility): you'd better use the value `hidden`. Except you're searching for `display: none` I think. A dropdown menu is definitely not something for somebody new to CSS I guess. Learn how to position and style blocks before playing with (advanced) hover effects

Answer (score 3):

You can use Pseduo-selectors to target the sub-list when you hover over the parent list.

**Here's the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uz9ZY/)**

All you need is this:

```
nav ul {
    position:relative;
    list-style-type: none;
    background-color:#eaeaea;
}

nav ul li ul {
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
    left:60px;
    background-color:#CCC;
}
nav ul li:hover ul {
    display:block;
}
```

This targets the sublist when the parent is hovered over, and overrides the `display:none;` command

Answer (score 1):

**HTML CODE:**

```
<nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="gear.html">Gear</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="p1.html">P1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="p2.html">P2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="p3.html">P3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="p4.html">P4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="p5.html">P5</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="news.html">News</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li> 
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

**CSS CODE:**

```
nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; 
}

nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
nav a{
    color:#000000;
}

nav ul li >ul {
    display: none;
}
nav ul li:hover >ul {
    display:block;
}
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nj9h7/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `visibility: collapse;` use `display:none` property because once you use `visibility` property there a space exist always.

you should try like this.

```
nav ul li >ul {
    display:none;
}
nav ul li:hover >ul {
    display:block;
}
```

A working Demo http://jsbin.com/xivogawu/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

The `visibility` property only hides an element without changing the layout (i.e. leaving gaps like you've noticed). Also, the `collapse` value only effects table rows and columns.

The best way to achieve your goal is to use the `display` property; try this instead:

```
nav ul li ul {
    display: none;
}
nav ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
```